# Excel VBA to add cumulative total to new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create a workbook that creates a new page and puts the cumulative total from two cells to add to the new totals entered on the new page.  I've been able to create a new page, but can't figure out the code for transferring the cumulative total to the next page. The total on each page is in J22, cumulative total for that total in K22 and the other total is in J32, cumulative total in K32.

Here is the code I have for the first part (Add new day):

```
Function NewShtName(NewDate As Date) As String
Dim Mon As String

Select Case Month(NewDate)
Case 1: Mon = "Jan"
Case 2: Mon = "Feb"
Case 3: Mon = "Mar"
Case 4: Mon = "Apr"
Case 5: Mon = "May"
Case 6: Mon = "Jun"
Case 7: Mon = "Jul"
Case 8: Mon = "Aug"
Case 9: Mon = "Sep"
Case 10: Mon = "Oct"
Case 11: Mon = "Nov"
Case 12: Mon = "Dec"
End Select

NewShtName = Mon & Day(NewDate)
End Function

Sub Create_New_Day()
'This adds a new day to the Daily Report
Dim NewDay As Integer
Dim Sht2Name As String
Dim NewName As String
Dim ThisDate As Date
Dim Temp As String
Dim DailyID As Integer


ThisDate = ActiveSheet.Range("J2")
DailyID = ActiveSheet.Range("K47")

If ActiveSheet.Range("J2") = "" Then
Ans2 = MsgBox("There is no date on the Report" & Chr(13) _
       & "Report for sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".", vbInformation, "Company Name")
Exit Sub
End If

NewName = NewShtName(ThisDate + 1)

For Sht = 2 To Sheets.Count
If Sheets(Sht).Name = NewName Then
    Ans1 = MsgBox("A sheet with the name " & NewName & " already exists." & Chr(13) _
        & Chr(13) & "Check to make sure that the sheet names" & Chr(13) _
        & "correspond to the dates on the dailies.", vbExclamation, "Company Name")
    Exit Sub
End If

If Sheets(Sht).Range("J2") = ThisDate + 1 Then
    Ans1 = MsgBox("Sheet " & Sheets(Sht).Name & " already has the date " & ThisDate + 1 & " on it." & Chr(13) _
    & Chr(13) & "A new day will not be added.", vbExclamation, "Company Name")
    Exit Sub
End If
Next Sht


ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet

NewDay = Sheets.Count

Sheets(NewDay).Range("J2") = ThisDate + 1
Sheets(NewDay).Name = NewName

Sht2Name = Sheets(2).Name

Sheets(NewDay).Range("K47") = DailyID + 1


With Sheets(NewDay)    'clears previous days comments

Range("C6:K11").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("C14:K19").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("C24:K29").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("C33:K38").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("C41:K46").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("D22:H22").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("G32:H32").Select
Selection.ClearContents

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I'm guessing by your "Month" case select that you don't know about the existing VBA [MonthName function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/monthname.php)?  Much shorter. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Idea, a hint for you, NOTE UNTESTED CODE.

```
NewDay = Sheets.Count
cmlSum=0
for sht=0 to NewDay
  cmlSum=Sheets(sht).Range("J22")+cmlSum
  Sheets(sht).Range("K22")=cmlSum
next
```

... and you need to correct any faults, as 
`Sht2Name = Sheets(2).Name` 
at least is not what you intend it to be.